# If I don't have WGA installed and install XP SP3 will it install WGA?

Tags: windows-xp, sp3, wga

I have an SP2 XP with no WGA. If I install a manually downloaded (from MS) SP3 will it force WGA on me?

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion from [this thread on ExtremeOverclocking.com](http://forums.extremeoverclocking.com/t292259.html) is that SP3 includes WGA, as does [this post from fpslabs.com](http://www.fpslabs.com/news/latest/microsoft-relaxes-wga-in-windows-xp-sp3) about the relaxation of the rules it operates under.

Comment: Well,  they can also relax the rules of the already installed WGA. It's not definitve proof it installs WGA if it's not installed, it can simply be a reconfiguration if WGA is installed.